# mysql GROUP BY but do not count with values that are already included in previous row

Tags: mysql

I have this SELECT but how can I reduce repetitive user_id that made action in 2017 and also in 2020. If there is the same user_id in 2017 so do not count with this user_id in 2020. Is it possible to rewrite in mysql? I just need to have unique user_ids in every group that do not exist in the other group. Thank you for every help :)

```
SELECT YEAR(l.datetime_created) AS year,
       COUNT(l.user_id) as count_of_users
FROM users_locations AS l
GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT(l.user_id)) as count_of_users`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you change `GROUP BY year` to `GROUP BY month`? Now your code does not even run.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [COUNT DISTINCT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php#:%7E:text=MySQL%20COUNT(DISTINCT)%20function%20returns,different%20non%2DNULL%20expr%20values.&text=Where%20expr%20is%20a%20given%20expression.&text=The%20following%20MySQL%20statement%20will,each%20group%20of%20%27cate_id%27.)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add distinct.

```
SELECT YEAR(l.datetime_created) AS year,
       -- add distinct term
       COUNT(distinct(l.user_id)) as count_of_users
       FROM users_locations AS l
GROUP BY YEAR(l.datetime_created);
```

**If you want by month:**

```
SELECT YEAR(l.datetime_created) AS year, 
   MONTH(l.datetime_created) AS month,
   -- add distinct term
   COUNT(distinct(l.user_id)) as count_of_users
FROM users_locations AS l
GROUP BY YEAR(l.datetime_created), MONTH(l.datetime_created)
order by YEAR(l.datetime_created), MONTH(l.datetime_created);
```